# Error in custom UIView class having interface loaded from .xib file

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to make a reusable `UIView` which I will use in several `UIViewController`s.
So I added a .xib file in my project and I drawn my interface, I added a class inherited from `UIView` and then I set up .xib class type same as the new class I have just added.

Next I dragged a outlet for .xib's main view in corresponding .h .

In `myCustomUIView` class I wrote this code to load the interface from .xib but it crashes at the line where I'm trying to load the nib file. Unfortunately compiler doesn't give me any error/reason. Please help me.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DropDownMenuViewInterface" owner:self  options:nil];
    [self addSubview: self.customView];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup File Owner for this xib? 
Check my image [image]

Instead of subclassing root view in you xib hierarchy - make the File Owner to be your view subclass

Comment: Yes, I solved the mystery. I only setted class for the first view in hierarchy instead of setting File's Owner class. Then I dragged from File's Owner to the control I want to hook up with a IBOutlet and now all is working. Badly I'm used only with Storyboards. Thanks!

Comment: I integrated the new custom UIView with one of my ViewControllers but I can't make this new view to be transparent. Is this a limitation of using this approach?

Comment: Hm, I belive that you should firstly set self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; so the only visible view is your 'customView'